# Suggested multiple linear regression algorithm

Tags: python

I would like to hear from you some ideas about an issue I have for solving the following problem:

I have a set of data (X) with a lot of variables. These variables affect the values stored in an array y
so that:

```
C0+C1*x11+C2*x12+C3*x13+...Cn*x1n=y1
C0+C1*x21+C2*x22+C3*x23+...Cn*x2n=y2
...
...
C0+C1*xm1+C2*xm2+c3*xm3+...Cn*xmn=ym
```

Where C(i) Are the coefficients of each variable (C0 is the constant value).

Now, each xij and each yi is an integer and NEVER lower than 40.
Plus, some of the C(i) *should* be 0 (they don't have any impact on the value y(i))
AND C(i) should NEVER be negative (C(i)>=0, for any i>=1, as the constant C(0) Will Be negative )

I've tried both the backwardElimination and the forward_selected algorithms, but they don't seem to behave like I'd hope, due to the additionals constraints reported above.

The code I'm using is this (taken from the net)

```
def forward_selected(data, response):
    remaining = set(data.columns)
    remaining.remove(response)
    selected = []
    current_score, best_new_score = 0.0, 0.0
    while remaining and current_score == best_new_score:
        scores_with_candidates = []
        for candidate in remaining:
            formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                                           ' + '.join(selected + [candidate]))
            score = smf.ols(formula, data).fit().rsquared_adj
            scores_with_candidates.append((score, candidate))
        scores_with_candidates.sort()
        best_new_score, best_candidate = scores_with_candidates.pop()
        if current_score < best_new_score:
            remaining.remove(best_candidate)
            selected.append(best_candidate)
            current_score = best_new_score
    formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                                   ' + '.join(selected))
    model = smf.ols(formula, data).fit()
    return model
```

where I put the full matrix of X|Y in data, and in response the name of the column of y.

Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using ordinary least squares from statsmodels.
You should try non negative least squares from scikit-learn to ensure the constraints you mentioned are respected. I think non negative least squares is not implemented in statsmodels. [Here is a scikit-learn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_nnls.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-nnls-py):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg_nnls = LinearRegression(positive=True)
y_pred_nnls = reg_nnls.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
r2_score_nnls = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_nnls)
print("NNLS R2 score", r2_score_nnls)
```

You can try running it first without forward selection or backward elimination. The non-negativity constraint will probably already set a few coefficients to 0. Then you can also substitute the scikit-learn model for the statsmodels one in your function.